# Multiple models with Sorcery gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorcery

I have a goal to have a User model and a Vendor model.  Think as if User is a company, and Vendor is employees where the company can create multiple employee accounts to associate to the company.

I have set up Sorcery to have User model and Vendor model but when signing in is where my issues are.

At the end of the sorcery file, there is this:

```
  config.user_class = "User"
```

I have tried:

```
  config.user_class = "User" || "Vendor"
```

When signing in, it will only search through the model that is first.
this:

```
  config.user_class = "User"
  config.user_class = "Vendor"
```

(in both orders, vice versa)
Whichever is last, that model works.  It will search only through the Vendor model if the Vendor model is last.

I looked into STI, but most of what I have seen is creating associated models that inherit from the one model.  Not much on multiple models for authentication for each, or any.  Is this a route to go into?

I need both User and Vendor to be able to sign in as separate accounts.

I have, in the past, used Devise to create multiple models with ease but Sorcery seems to be giving issues?

Is there a way to set up Sorcery to allow multiple models?

Answer (score 1):

Sorcery does allow STI though the `user.subclasses_inherit_config` setting in `config/initializers/sorcery.rb`. You can set it to `true` then inherit your Vendor class from User.

I've never used the Gem but I would look at just adding a role to your user class and use authorization.

Comment: I tried adding the Vendor model to that from the sorcery wikis but it seems there is more setup required on the side of the sessions.  Either that or I'm completely missing the ball.  If i were to use roles, how would i go about relating through associations through a single model? That's where I went ahead and created 2... couldn't think of a way to make associations from one single model to itself

Comment: Looks like there is a concept, self referential models which went right over my head.  Should had thought of that.  Would there be any downside to using this instead of (switching to devise) creating multiple auth models?

Comment: If you are stuck with using Sorcery, then a self referencing model seems like the best option.

Comment: Not stuck with it but been using it for this app to learn more about authentication.  Devise does everything so I just wanted a bit of a more manual approach to get more of an understanding.  That seems the best route for now. thanks